# Eclipse Aptana Studio 3, xdebug configuration for Windows with virtual machine

Tags: php, eclipse, virtual-machine, xdebug, aptana

I have a problem to debug php files with Aptana Studio. I don't know is it possible to be done because the way of working is a little bit complicated.

Actually I have my source PHP files into my local Windows machine, also my Aptana studio. The Apache server has been installed on the Ubuntu virtual machine and has as source the files of my local Windows machine.

From the web browser into my local Windows I charge the URL of the virtual machine and I would like to debug from Eclipse/Aptana.

I have to configure Xdebug in Eclipse, but I don't find issues how to do in my case.

Is there someone having the same problem or idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly we found the solution for **Eclipse PDT** but the same is valid for Aptana just the eclipse configurations are a little bit different.

In order to implements the remote debug you must to install the xdebug packages where the virtual machine is (in our case the Ubuntu virtual machine).

After into the **/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini** you must to configure the 2 lines :

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on 
xdebug.remote_host=192.X.XX
```

where the **remote_host** is the IP of your local machine containg the eclipse.

Further you must to change the **eclipse** configuration **Windows->Preference->PHP->Debug->Debuggers->Xdebug** to put the debug port (same as in xdebug.ini file - default 9000), and set **Accept remote session (JIT)** to **any**.

For Aptana change the xdebug configuration by searching where Accept remote session (JIT) is.